# Ctrl+Shift key combination in Python

Tags: python, keyboard

I am working on a snippet that requires user interaction: either an `Esc` press or a `Ctrl+Shift` press.

I am struggling with combining `Ctrl+Shift` though. The below code works fine with the `Esc` button. However, when pressing `Ctrl+Shift` initially (before pressing `Esc`) it doesn't print anything, while after having pressed `Esc` at least once, it works for `Shift` but not for `Ctrl`- which is not what I intended. How can I bind `Ctrl` and `Shift` together?

```
from pynput import keyboard

COMBINATIONS = [
    { keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.ctrl },
    { keyboard.Key.esc }
]

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def execute():
    print ("Pressed!")

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: How do keys get removed from the set if you release them?

Comment: @paxdiablo indeed. I edited the code above with an on_release() method. But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a `print(key)` at the start of `on_press`, you'll see that the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key generates either a `ctrl_l` or `ctrl_r` key (depending on which one you've pressed), *not* a `ctrl` key.

So you either have to handle either of them, ending up with some monstrous `any/all/any` code snippet, or just translate at the top:

```
if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_l or key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_r:
    key = keyboard.Key.ctrl
```

---

A version which handles this with a translation function `xlate()` (for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> *and* <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys, since the latter appear to generate `shift/shift_r`), as well as detecting releases of keys, can be seen below:

```
from pynput import keyboard

COMBINATIONS = [
    { keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.ctrl },
    { keyboard.Key.esc }
]

current = set()

def execute():
    print ("Pressed!")

def xlate(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_l or key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_r:
        return keyboard.Key.ctrl
    if key == keyboard.Key.shift_l or key == keyboard.Key.shift_r:
        return keyboard.Key.shift
    return key

def on_release(key):
    key = xlate(key)
    if key in current:
        current.remove(key)

def on_press(key):
    #print(key) # for debugging purposes.
    key = xlate(key)
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, @paxdiablo! :)